# Google Calendar API recurrence event reset

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I am trying to edit an recurrence event with exceptions. I do not know how I can reset recurrence event (remove all recurrence exceptions). I found [the API endpoint](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/reset) but it does not work (does not exists).

What is the correct way to remove all recurrence exceptions of the recurrence event? The result should be pure recurrence event without any exception (only defined by `RRULE` in `recurrence[]`).

I tried to delete recurrence exceptions but the result was canceled recurrence exception (the recurrence exception was still there). My "hack" is update recurrence event to nonrecurrence event by set `recurrence[] = null`. Then I set `recurrence[]` to `RRULE` and it works (Google calendar recreate recurrence events).

I can not make it work if every recurrence event of recurence event is an recurrence exception. The parent recurrence event is cancelled but contains "confirmed" recurrence exceptions and there are troubles with this state.

Thanks.

Comment: Hello @FandaOG, are you able to retrieve all the recurrent events and then compare them with one that doesn't have any exceptions and then eventually updating the one with exceptions to match the original one? Cheers!

Comment: Hello @ale13, are you sure if it is the correct way how to do it? I think if exception does not exist any more then should be removed not edited to original scheduled time.

Comment: Could you explain further what happens when you try to delete the recurrent exception instances as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/recurringevents#modifying_or_deleting_instances)? My first thoughts is to get and delete these exception instances. If that is not possible maybe you could try deleting the recurrent event and creating a new one which is the same as the previous one. Cheers!